Why is this js file loaded and executed on each page change?
I have two page called first.html and second.html.
The template of the two page is the same except for first and second text. Is an example to understand an issue.

first.html:

<!doctype html>

<body hx-boost="true">
    First page!

    <a href="/second.html">Go to second page</a>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@2.0.2"
        integrity="sha384-Y7hw+L/jvKeWIRRkqWYfPcvVxHzVzn5REgzbawhxAuQGwX1XWe70vji+VSeHOThJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


second.html:

<!doctype html>

<body hx-boost="true">
    Second page!

    <a href="/first.html">Go to first page</a>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@2.0.2"
        integrity="sha384-Y7hw+L/jvKeWIRRkqWYfPcvVxHzVzn5REgzbawhxAuQGwX1XWe70vji+VSeHOThJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


test.js:

let players = 0;

If I launch a server and open the browser to http://localhost:3000/first.html and then I click on "Go to second page" link I can see in the console the error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'players' has already been declared (at test.js:1:1)

Why?
I expect it to be loaded and executed just one time!
How can I fix?

Whether it gets LOADED twice or not, it's certainly going to get EXECUTED twice, but the global variables should be reset on page load.  I'm guessing your code doesn't really look like that.

From the documentation for hx-boost, https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-boost/, it looks like this is loading the second page in dynamically and not doing a full page load.
I would probably move the script tags to a <head> section and so only the <body> is updating and not the shared script.

Understanding issue:
The issue might be related to how HTMX handles content updates and script execution. The script test.js is re-executing with players variable being declared twice within the same scope.
Possible Solutions:

Script logic encapsulation:
// test.js

(() => {
    let players = 0;
    // other logic
})();





Use of var instead of let:
// test.js
var players = 0;




Are you AI right?

AI in human form

Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

I also have access to review questions and answers, for mistakes or malpractices just like you.

I thought that would be the term for it. Please enlighten me with the correct term. Besides that, you may check my entire answer history, I have been answering before ChatGPT, and never needed it to rephrase my answers.

I did - A lot of answers just consist out of "try this", "add this", etc.

Would you like me to share the ones with explanations? :)

And I'll do you one better... not sure if you can do that but do checkout the edit history if you can. If you think even that is AI, downvote delete whatever you wanna do.
